# How does one assign values to nested [NSObject: AnyObject] dictionaries?

Tags: macos, swift, dictionary, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I would like to have a Dictionary of Dictionaries. I'm coming from mostly a Python background, where I can simply allocate and assign a top-level key to be a new dictionary, then use a reference to that dictionary to update it no matter how deeply it is nested.

I am trying to do the same thing in Swift. I am using `[NSObject: AnyObject]` because it must be bridgeable to `NSDictionary` so I can store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

Here is an example Playground:

```
import Cocoa

var foo = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
foo["aa_key"] = "aa_value"
println(foo)

foo["bb_key"] = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
println(foo)

if var bar = foo["bb_key"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {
    bar["cc_key"] = "cc_value"
    println("bar: \(bar)")
} else {
    println("Could not get bb dictionary")
}
// bb_key is still an _empty_ dictionary in foo!
println("foo: \(foo)")
```

The resulting output in the console (not the playground) is:

```
[aa_key: aa_value]
[aa_key: aa_value, bb_key: { }]
bar: [cc_key: cc_value]
foo: [aa_key: aa_value, bb_key: { }]
```

I can see that in the section where the Optional result of the downcast is unwrapped into `bar`, that assignments to the `bar` Dictionary are correct. However, when I later print `foo`, the changes have not made it.

It appears that bar is not a proper reference to the dictionary that is stored in `foo["bb_key"]`. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift all collection types are value types unlike reference types in Objective-C, that means the object in `bar` is not the same object as in `foo["bb_key"]`

You have to reassign / update the value in `foo["bb_key"]`

```
var foo = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
foo["aa_key"] = "aa_value"
println(foo)

foo["bb_key"] = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
println(foo)

if var bar = foo["bb_key"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] {
  bar["cc_key"] = "cc_value"
  foo.updateValue(bar, forKey: "bb_key")
  println("bar: \(bar)")
} else {
  println("Could not get bb dictionary")
}
// bb_key is still an _empty_ dictionary in foo!
println("foo: \(foo)")
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed this nuance in the discussion of value types vs references. This is definitely a departure from every language I've used in the last 10 years.